# How to POST a request in Postman with two format like form-data and x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, postman

I need test my Web API project and the function get two types data on a request.

I need to send Key/Value with x-www-form-urlencoded and at the same time send a file in form-data format together.

[image: File to send]

[image: form url encoded data]

Comment: Does it have to be x-www-form-urlencoded? If not just use a query parameter or another form-data parameter.

Comment: I need to send an object as parameter and an attachment file at the same time. query parameter is not acceptable for the request.

Comment: @ErfanSoleymani Are you using asp.net core or framework?

Comment: @Div We are using ASP.Net Web Api and I must test the result of Web Api.

Comment: we did the request with angular and it works. but I need a postman test for our document. So the Web Api Works fine.

Comment: I changed the input and send one type of data and works find. it seems there is not any way to send multiple type with body in postman. hop on new updates they consider that option.